# Encoding data to barcodes

Tags: electrical-engineering

How the patterns or widths will be given to numbers while encoding data to barcodes like for 1 it will be 2221 and for 2 it is 2122. I didn't understand how these widths are given

Comment: Welcome to engineering.SE! I don't think the question is within the scope of our side. For now it does not sound like an engineering problem to me. How the encoding works seems to be more of a computational problem.